# Project Lombok AllArgsConstructor not working

Tags: java, constructor, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

It seems like many people are having this problem, but none of the problems i have researched so far are that basic like my problem.

I only got this object:

[image]

and a basic call in my main method:

[image]

Bamm... already not working. The compilataion fails with this error

[image]

I am using IntelliJ and have installed the Lombok plugin.

[image]

If it helps... here is my build.gradle:
[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: Oh and my Annotation processing is enabled inside my Idea settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lombok uses the annotation processor to do its magic so you have to add lombok annotationProcessor dependency in your build.gradle file. Add this line inside your `dependencies` block:

```
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
```

Comment: it worked ! Why in the world didnt they include this on the official Maven repository -> gradle include instruction ?

Comment: What do you mean? It's all there: https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Comment: I just meant the Mave repository description for gradle: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.18.16